# Remove row if it is within a minute of the next python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this data frame

```
data = {'Date': [np.datetime64('2005-02-25 01:30:10'), np.datetime64('2005-02-25 01:31:10'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25 02:36:10'),
                 np.datetime64('2005-02-25 02:45:10'), np.datetime64('2005-02-25 02:45:50'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25 03:54:20'),
                 np.datetime64('2005-02-25 03:55:10'),np.datetime64('2005-02-25 05:30:10'), np.datetime64('2005-02-25 06:30:10'),
                 np.datetime64('2005-02-25 06:30:30')],
        'Value':[1,4,6,7,3,6,7,8,3,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Date                Value
0   2005-02-25 01:30:10 1
1   2005-02-25 01:31:10 4
2   2005-02-25 02:36:10 6
3   2005-02-25 02:45:10 7
4   2005-02-25 02:45:50 3
5   2005-02-25 03:54:20 6
6   2005-02-25 03:55:10 7
7   2005-02-25 05:30:10 8
8   2005-02-25 06:30:10 3
9   2005-02-25 06:30:30 2
```

How would I go about removing the first row when the next row is within one minute of it, without doing it manually.

So my expected output would be:

```
    Date                Value
1   2005-02-25 01:31:10 4
2   2005-02-25 02:36:10 6
4   2005-02-25 02:45:50 3
6   2005-02-25 03:55:10 7
7   2005-02-25 05:30:10 8
9   2005-02-25 06:30:30 2
```

Please let me know how to do this

Comment: I suggest that you look at using a for loop to compare each entry's time with that of the one before and then use the drop command to remove the rows that are within 1m of the one before

Comment: Ive found a way of comparing the old time to new time. How would I do it so theres not greater than one minute, e.g. ` date_diff > 1 min `?

Comment: take a look at what functions you can carry out on the panda type `datetime64`, there may be a way to carry out that comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) wth subtract, then [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), divide by [`DataFrame.floordiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.floordiv.html) and last filter if greater like `1` or missing values (for match last value) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['Date'].shift(-1).sub(df['Date']).dt.total_seconds().floordiv(60)

df = df[s.isna() | s.gt(1)]
print (df)
                 Date  Value
1 2005-02-25 01:31:10      4
2 2005-02-25 02:36:10      6
4 2005-02-25 02:45:50      3
6 2005-02-25 03:55:10      7
7 2005-02-25 05:30:10      8
9 2005-02-25 06:30:30      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, hope it helps

```
df['flag'] = df[['Date']].apply(lambda x:[False if pd.Timedelta(x[i+1]-x[i]).total_seconds()/60 <=1 else True for i in range(0,len(x)-1)])
df = df[df['flag']!=False].drop('flag',axis=1)
```